# Call post-id from URL hash not working?

Tags: javascript, get-the-id

I'm trying to have a modal box open by default when calling it by its id.

For example, if i enter the url `www.mysite.com#post-28` (#post28 being the ID of the post)

I will land with the moadal box and the content of the post-28.

For this I have been using the following jquery ( iattach a basic version of the code):

```
<script>
 jQuery(function ($) { 

 function popModal() {
  { alert("Your book is overdue.")
    };
    }

 var hash = window.location.hash;
 if (hash.substring(1) == 'post-<? the_ID(); ?>') {
 popModal();
}
 });
</script>
```

Which is not working when im calling dynamically `post-<? the_ID(); ?>`

However if I use this code instead:

```
 <script>
 jQuery(function ($) { 

 function popModal() {
  { alert("Your book is overdue.")
    };
    }

 var hash = window.location.hash;
 if (hash.substring(1) == 'post-17') {
 popModal();
}
 });
</script>
```

( post-17 being a post ID),

It does work.

I believe the problem is related how I call the post by `<? the_ID ?>`

any help will be incredible !

Thanks

--- EDIT ---

This is how i called my JS and seems to crash:

```
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeeo_scripts' );

 function themeeo_scripts() {
// Load stylesheets
wp_register_style('theme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css',array('bootstrap'));
wp_register_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css');
wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
wp_register_style('owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.css');
wp_register_style('tether', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/tether.min.css');
wp_register_style('responsive-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css',array('bootstrap'));
wp_register_style('custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css',array('bootstrap'));

// wp_enqueue_style('tether');
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');
wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome');
wp_enqueue_style('style-dynamic');
wp_enqueue_style('responsive-styles');
wp_enqueue_style('theme-style');
wp_enqueue_style('custom-style');

if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}



// Load jQuery scripts
 wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', array('jquery'));
wp_register_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.custom.js', array('jquery'));

wp_register_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'));
wp_register_script('owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'));
wp_register_script('tether', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/tether.min.js', array('jquery'));
 wp_register_script('velocity', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/velocity.js', array('jquery'));
wp_register_script('velocityui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/velocity.ui.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_register_script('helium-parallax-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/helium.parallax.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_register_script('urlhash', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/urlhash.js', array('jquery'));



wp_localize_script( 'custom', 'menuToggleText', array(
    'open'   => esc_html__( 'Open child menu' ),
    'close'  => esc_html__( 'Close child menu' ),
) );



wp_enqueue_script('helium-parallax-js');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('tether');
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', '', '', '', true);
wp_enqueue_script('owl-carousel', '', '', '', true);
wp_enqueue_script('tether', '', '', '', true);
wp_enqueue_script('custom', '', '', '', true);
wp_enqueue_script('skrollr.js', '', '', '', true);
wp_enqueue_script('velocity', '', '', '', true);

wp_enqueue_script('velocityui', '', '', '', true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'urlhash', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/urlhash.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

 if ( is_single() ){
    $localization = array(
        'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'urlhash', 'localized_object', $localization );

 }


 }
```

Comment: Have you tried do use `json_encode` in your value before passing to JavaScript? see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740549/6630308) so you can get a reference.

Answer (score 0):

That obviously won't work since you can't get the ID of the post by doing PHP calls in a javascript code. By the way, the short PHP tag should never be used due to conflicts. You should used the full `<?php` tag.

Now, about your problem. What you need to pass the ID is a localization. Include your script in a js file, and enqueue it using this piece of code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'some_function' );
function some_function(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'some-handler', 'FULL URL HERE', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

Now, to pass the ID to the script, localize the post's ID by extending your code to this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'some_function' );
function some_function(){
    // Enqueue our JS file
    wp_enqueue_script( 'some-handler', 'FULL URL HERE', array( 'jquery' ) );
    // If we are on a single post, add the post's ID
    if ( is_single() ){
        $localization = array(
            'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
        );
        wp_localize_script( 'some-handler', 'localized_object', $localization );
    }
}
```

We're half way done. At this point, you can access your post's ID directly in your JS file:

```
(function($){ 

    function popModal() {
       window.alert("Your book is overdue.");
    }

    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash.substring(1) == 'post-' + localized_object.post_id ) {
        popModal();
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Pretty cool stuff, ha?

Comment: Thanks Jack for all this, sounds fantastic !

regarding both add_actions ; those should be added to the functions.php of the theme ?

Come back ot you once i made it work :)

Comment: @thebigE You're welcome. The second action is actually an expansion of the first time, and yes it goes in the theme's `functions.php` file. The js script goes in a js file, without the `<script></script>`.

Comment: digging in to it but im havig in the console a localized_object is not defined :(

Comment: Did you check the handler's names? This is a working function i pulled for you from my own theme.

Comment: yes, i think it s conflicting because i had already my js declared like that, and im not use to deal with handler, i usually call js in the footer

Comment: Then you can add the script to the end of your js file in the footer, and localize the js. Make sure the js is already enqueued, or it can't be localized.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62526/discussion-between-thebige-and-jack-johansson).

Comment: trying this way but i dont seem to be luck, Im not in a single page but calling this from a page template

Comment: Well then you need to change the conditional to match the page you are on. We can talk [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop) if you wish.

Comment: yes the problem is coming from there, I have paste how my script are being loaded, if i call them as it is originally, hoe van i add the function localized_object into it ?

Thanks a lot, really apprecaite

Comment: You haven't changed the `some_function` name on your `add_action`. It's not even calling the enqueue.

Comment: Just move the `if ( ... ) { ... }` after the `wp_enqueue_script('velocityui', '', '', '', true);` before the closing bracket.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I have edit again y questions with my encryption, still no luck, i can the js is being call now, it's just still the Uncaught ReferenceError: localized_object is not defined

If you can have a last look . . i suppose is just i dont manage to wrap the code to that script . .

Comment: if i change the is_single by something else ( ex get_posts), the error disappear - however, the alert doesnt display - nothign happen :(

Comment: any idea ? Really appreciate your time . . . thank you

Comment: Sorry I don't get the problem. If it's on a single page, then `get_the_ID()` will return the ID. Since you no longer see the error, I assume the localization is correct, there might be syntax a problem in your jScript.

Comment: ok, ive been tryting everything, but still having the Uncaught ReferenceError: localization is not defined
 :(

Comment: ok, it is due to the is_single, it works if i call this from the url of a single post. but if i call from the category page or homepage ( page template) it's not working :(

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work :) The post ID only exists on the single post page.